# How to use raw SQL query to find entity in Moqui?

Tags: java, mysql, erp, moqui

I think there are very good way to find entity data from MySQL through view-entity. But here I am in some situations that I need to use very complex query from MySQL databases what likes `max` function with `group by` and `order by` criterias. Is there any way to use complex query in Moqui?

Answer (score 3):

Use a script tag and in it you can obtain a connection to the database through the [ExecutionContext](https://www.moqui.org/javadoc/org/moqui/context/ExecutionContext.html) `getEntity` and then `getConnection`.

```
ExecutionContext ec = context.ec
Connection con = ec.getEntity().getConnection(groupName)
def statement = con.createStatement()
def queryResult = statement.executeQuery(query)
```

Then just process the results as described in [java.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) documentation and set it to a previously defined field tag.

Comment: This is just general concept to create DB connection and execute query. But I am looking for something like if Moqui Framwork has its own way to execute raw sql query or not.

Comment: Well, if you get the connection you should be able to run a raw sql query

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve pretty complex queries with View Entities, indeed. Have a look to `entity-definition-2.1.xsd` file for further details. You can use aggregate functions with `<alias function="...` and the GROUP BY clause will be generated automatically. `<order-by>` elements are supported too.

Besides, you can take advantage of any SQL function and complex expressions by nesting `<complex-alias>` elements. Remember that you can create INNER JOIN entity combinations with `<member-entity  join-from-alias="...` and OUTER JOIN with `<member-entity  join-from-alias="..." join-optional="true"`.

Try to stick to SQL standards whenever possible to keep the view entity being database engine independent.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the solution from @lombardo2:

```
<script>
    org.moqui.context.ExecutionContext ec = context.ec
    java.sql.Connection con = ec.getEntity().getConnection('transactional')
    def statement = con.createStatement()
    def result = statement.executeQuery("select PAYMENT_ID, PAYMENT_METHOD_ID from PAYMENT where PAYMENT_ID = '$paymentId';")
    result.next()
</script>
<log message="======result1: ${result.getString(1)}"/>
<log message="======result2: ${result.getString(2)}"/>
```